# Q: Set Folder's path according to it's title in a list with SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, typescript, pnpjs

I am creating a folder inside a List with the following code:

```
TypeScript
import {sp} from "@pnp/sp";

const shpList = sp.site.rootWeb.lists.getById(ListId);

shpList.items.add(
{
  Title: folderName,
  FileSystemObjectType: 1,
  ContentTypeId: '0x0120',
  FileLeafRef: folderName,
  DisplayName: folderName
} )
```

And it does create the folder, but the navigation displays `130_.000` as the folder. (It's the item's ID plus underscore, dot and three zeros)

Is there a way to create the item so it uses the title as the navigation?

Is there any place I can look for the default properties of SharePoint?

---

Here a list of the properties I have already tested:

- Name (and name) | value: folderName | result: error (not registered property)
- FileRef | value: folderName | result: Does not seem to do anything
- Path (and path) | value: folderName | result: error (not registered property)
- Folder | value: folderName | result: error (primitive value not null)
- Url (& url & URL) | value: folderName | result: error (not registered property)

Comment: Have you tried setting `Name` property??

Comment: yep, I guess I will list all the properties that I already tested.

Comment: Ok. Add all the approaches you tried. that will be helpful to understand and answer your question.

Comment: I Have tried creating folder using `'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ListInternalNameListItem' }, 
         "Title": "Folder 10",
            "FileLeafRef": "Folder 10",     // No effect here
            "FileSystemObjectType": 1,         
   "ContentTypeId":"0x0120"`. And it is creating folders correctly.

Comment: When you access the folder in the list, does the navigation bar displays **listName > folderName**? In my case it displays **listName > id_.000**, but when I create the folder manually it does display the folderName.

Comment: Yes, it does show the name of Folder and not id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is creating the folder then updating it with the right FileLeafRef like so:

```
let newFolder = {
        ContentTypeId: '0x0120',
        Title: folderName
      };


  shpList.items.add( newFolder )
          .then((value) =>
          {
            shpList.items.getById( value.data.Id )
            .update({FileLeafRef: folderName})
            .then(() =>
            {
              // The folder is not created as intented
            }
          } );
```